# AngularJS: Delay disappear with $timeout

Tags: angularjs, timeout

when the mouse moves on the .mousemove DIV, the .show DIV appear and then if the mouse did not move in 3 seconds, the .show DIV disappear.

```
<div class="mousemove" ng-mousemove="myToggle()" ng-model="loading" ></div>
<div class="show" ng-show="loading"></div>

$scope.myToggle = function() {
    $scope.loading = true; 
    $timeout(
        function() {
            $scope.loading = false;
        }, 
    3000);
}
```

I have do something but when I move the mouse on the .mousemove DIV constantly,the .show DIV will twinkle.What should I do,and I'm new to AngularJS. 
here is my demo: http://embed.plnkr.co/WbhqAQ4JJvOfuCN4tI3I/preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cancel the $timeout before restarting it if it is already running.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('myController', function($scope, $timeout) {

    $scope.myToggle = function() {
      // Check to see if there already is a $scope.loading timer
      if($scope.loading){
        // if there is then use the $timeout.cancel() method
        $timeout.cancel($scope.loading);
      }
      // Initialize the $timeout into the $scope.loading propert
      $scope.loading = $timeout(
        function() {
          $scope.loading = false;
      }, 3000);
    }
});
```

Demo: http://embed.plnkr.co/WbqGbFG9JTVNXJW970l8/preview

Comment: I so sorry for reply you now,because the network is so bad.Now it works successfully with your code.But I don't understand "$scope.loading" is not setted to "true" in your code,How it works to show the .show DIV?

Comment: @hollton the `$timeout` returns a promise https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout and hence it is not `false`.  Whilst not specifically `true` it is `truthy` which is enough to pass the `if` clause http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/

Answer (score 1):

You have to clear your timeout before relaunching it, as follow:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('myController', function($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.timeout;
    $scope.myToggle = function() {
        $scope.loading = true;

        window.clearTimeout($scope.timeout);
        $scope.timeout = window.setTimeout(function() {
            $scope.$apply(function() {
                $scope.loading = false;
            });
        }, 3000);
    }
});
```

See [working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/NIVkH91MtrqiUg4YVHb7?p=preview)

Comment: Fristly,I so sorry for reply you now,because the network is so bad.Your code works well but I choose other's answer.thank you anyway.

Comment: I try,but I haven't get 15 reputation, can't vote  (。_。)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things wrong with this plunk.

First, there's no reason to use ng-model here. Just set it as a scope variable, seeing as you are editing it from the controller anyway.

Second, mousemove will execute continuously. Every time you move the mouse it's going to create a new timeout and it's not going to cancel the old one. This is why it flickers. It's also very inefficient to call this function and constanly make calls to `$timeout.cancel()` and `$timeout(function() {  }, 3000)`.

Instead consider using mouseenter and mouseleave and make sure you cancel old timeouts.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
  <div class="mousemove" ng-mouseenter="enter()" ng-mouseleave="leave()"></div>
  <div class="show" ng-show="loading"></div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('myController', function($scope, $timeout) {

  var timeoutCanceller = null;

  $scope.loading = false;

  $scope.enter = function() {
    cancelTimeout();
    $scope.loading = true;
  };

  $scope.leave = function() {
    timeoutCanceller = $timeout(function() {
      $scope.loading = false;
    }, 3000);
  };

  function cancelTimeout() {
    if (timeoutCanceller) $timeout.cancel(timeoutCanceller);
  }
});
```

[Here is a working demo.](http://embed.plnkr.co/OQoHKMdZnJx5bfov2VnE/preview)

**Edit:** Might also be a good idea to bind those events to a parent container instead of directly on the element. If that loader is an overlay bringing that up might accidentally call the mouseleave event. Also gives you more options for styling.

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
  <div ng-mouseenter="enter()" ng-mouseleave="leave()">
    <div class="mousemove"></div>
    <div class="show" ng-show="loading"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I so sorry for reply you now,because the network is so bad. I learn a lot from your suggestions,however,maybe I didn't discribe what I want clearly.When the mouse  is motionless in the frist DIV,the second DIV disappear instead of leave DIV.And now I have already solved.thank you anyway.